# How to correctly add event listener inside a class in javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, events, binding

I found out yesterday that there are classes in JS. So I started to play around little bit and can't get my code right:

```
var someImg = "blabla.png";
class Piece {
    constructor(position, image, value) {
        this.image = image;
        this.position = position;
        this.value = value;
    }
    setPieces() {
        document.getElementById(this.position).innerHTML = "<img width='50' src='" + this.image + "'>";
        document.getElementById(this.position).addEventListener("click", this.ShowMoves);
    }
    showMoves() {
        console.log(this) //shows html element (<div class=...), instead of an object
        this.value = "new value"; // so this doesn't work
    }
}
piece = new Piece("someid", someImg, "some value"); 
piece.setPieces();
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do here, is to attach `onclick` event to every object that called `setPieces()` method and then work with the object. But instead, `this` keyword returns an `HTML element`, instead of an `object`. I think I get why it happens, but can't figure out the way to add a click event and not lose my object in process.

Comment: `...addEventListener("click", this.showMoves.bind(this))` will get you the correct `this`

Comment: or `document.getElementById(this.position).addEventListener("click", () => this.ShowMoves());` since arrow function inherits `this` from parent.